# Update database that has same key with using a new different values

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Lets say I have a table like this,

```
|id|area_id|area_values|
|1 |12     |value 1    |
|2 |12     |value 2    |
|3 |12     |value 3    |
|4 |01     |value 4    |
```

and I would like to update only those that have an area of 12. My new values is an array `$values = ['newvalue1,'newvalue2',newvalue3']`;

I have tried using array_map like this.

```
$ids = Area::where('area_id', 12)->pluck('id')->toArray();
array_map(function ($id) {
   array_map(function($areaValue){
     Area::find($id)->update(['area_values' => $areaValue]);
   }, $values);
}, $ids)
```

But the problem I encountered was it's being updated with only the first value of the new array, which is newValue1

What is the best approach on doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do like this :

```
$values = ['newvalue1','newvalue2','newvalue3'];
$ids = Area::where('area_id', 12)->pluck('id')->toArray();

foreach($ids as $index=>$id){
      Area::where('id',$id)->update(['area_values'=>$values[$index]); 
}
```

Comment: yea it did work, i forgot to loop through into the $values, thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Laravel** batch updates Model

Make adjustments to the laravel Eloquent to make no SQL injections

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;

use DB;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

/**
 * Students Table Model
 */
class Students extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'students';

    //Update Batch
    public function updateBatch($multipleData = [])
    {
        try {
            if (empty($multipleData)) {
                throw new \Exception("The data cannot be empty");
            }
            $tableName = DB::getTablePrefix() . $this->getTable(); // Table name
            $firstRow  = current($multipleData);

            $updateColumn = array_keys($firstRow);
            // The default is to update with id as a condition, and if there is no id, the first field as a condition
            $referenceColumn = isset($firstRow['id']) ? 'id' : current($updateColumn);
            unset($updateColumn[0]);
            // Splicing SQL statement
            $updateSql = "UPDATE " . $tableName . " SET ";
            $sets      = [];
            $bindings  = [];
            foreach ($updateColumn as $uColumn) {
                $setSql = "`" . $uColumn . "` = CASE ";
                foreach ($multipleData as $data) {
                    $setSql .= "WHEN `" . $referenceColumn . "` = ? THEN ? ";
                    $bindings[] = $data[$referenceColumn];
                    $bindings[] = $data[$uColumn];
                }
                $setSql .= "ELSE `" . $uColumn . "` END ";
                $sets[] = $setSql;
            }
            $updateSql .= implode(', ', $sets);
            $whereIn   = collect($multipleData)->pluck($referenceColumn)->values()->all();
            $bindings  = array_merge($bindings, $whereIn);
            $whereIn   = rtrim(str_repeat('?,', count($whereIn)), ',');
            $updateSql = rtrim($updateSql, ", ") . " WHERE `" . $referenceColumn . "` IN (" . $whereIn . ")";
            // Pass in the preprocessed SQL statement and the corresponding binding data
            return DB::update($updateSql, $bindings);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
// Array of batch updates
$students = [
    ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'bill', 'area_values' => 'values1'],
    ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'smith', 'area_values' => 'values2'],
];

// Update batch
app(Students::class)->updateBatch($students);
```

The generated SQL statement is as follows:

```
UPDATE pre_students
SET NAME = CASE
WHEN id = 1 THEN
    'bill'
WHEN id = 2 THEN
    'smith'
ELSE
    NAME
END,
 email = CASE
WHEN id = 1 THEN
    'values1'
WHEN id = 2 THEN
    'values2'
ELSE
    email
END
WHERE
    id IN (1, 2)
```